# How to reference .Net Framework Class Library in Documentation

Tags: .net, documentation

I am working on some documentation and need to reference the .Net Framework Class Library. Does anyone know the best way to do this? I was thinking something like the following:

> .Net Framework Class Library,
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx

Wasn't sure if I should include a date or something. I couldn't find one on the webpage, maybe today's date?

Update: By documentation, I do not mean documentation within my source code. I am talking about requirements documents and User Manuals. These documents are read and approved by people that do not have software engineering/computer science degrees. I have to be very explicit with my references (thus why I can't just say "You can use anything in the System.Math namespace" without providing a reference to the .Net Framework documentation).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about the software development process and software engineering, including quality assurance, architecture & design are off topic on Stack Overflow. You might try posting on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254571/1677912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN library links notoriously change constantly.  There's little reason to believe that this will stop happening, it is likely that the comment in the link will go dead.

Frankly, documenting framework classes in your source code is not very useful.  Any .NET programmer knows how to look them up.

Comment: I am not talking about referencing it in my source code. I'm actually referencing it in a requirements document. We are allowing C# code as a portion of an input file (we dynamically compile and run using CodeDOM). I need to reference the framework because I don't want to have to specifically document everything you can do when I could just reference the .Net Class Library.

Comment: Not sure, why not just reference it by the full type name (including the namespace)?

Comment: I work in a business where our documents are read and approved by people other than software engineers/computer scientists. If I want to say "You can use anything in the System.Math namespace", they wouldn't know how to look that up unless I put some sort of reference for them to research it.

Comment: Weird stuff, you want to provide links for people that wouldn't have the foggiest idea what the linked info means?  I can't really reverse engineer what you need to get this approval you are looking for.  As long as this happens within the next 6 to 12 months, providing the link should be fine.

Comment: Haha, sounds good. I guess thats really my only option! The question was mainly just to see if anyone had any other good ideas on how to reference :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of documentation you are working on?

Since you are referencing a native component of the framework, like the .NET Class Library, you do no need to include a date to reference it. If it were you that created the component, then you should put your information to document it.

Just reference the .NET Class Library as a native component of the platform you are using, I guess that's enough =)

Comment: See comment on @Hans Passant answer